# Azure Terraform import bacpac into SQL Server with public network access disabled

Tags: sql-server, azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a SQL Server in Azure with public network access disabled

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "sql_server" {
    name                          = var.db-server-name
    resource_group_name           = var.resource_group
    location                      = var.location
    version                       = "12.0"
    administrator_login           = local.login
    administrator_login_password  = local.password
    minimum_tls_version           = "1.2"
    public_network_access_enabled = false
    tags = var.tags
}
```

For accessing the server, I am creating a private endpoint:

```
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "sqlserver_private_endpoint" {
    name                = "sqlserver-private-endpoint"
    location            = var.location
    resource_group_name = var.resource_group
    subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.db_subnet.id
    private_service_connection {
        name                           = "sqlserver-psc"
        is_manual_connection           = false
        private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_mssql_server.sql_server.id
        subresource_names              = ["sqlServer"]
    }
    tags = var.tags
}
```

I am then trying to create/import a database from Blob-Storage

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "sql_server_database" {
    name                        = var.db-name
    server_id                   = azurerm_mssql_server.sql_server.id
    collation                   = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
    auto_pause_delay_in_minutes = 60
    max_size_gb                 = 32
    min_capacity                = 0.5
    read_replica_count          = 0
    read_scale                  = false
    sku_name                    = "GP_S_Gen5_1"
    zone_redundant              = false
    import {
        storage_uri                  = var.storage-url
        storage_key                  = var.storage-key
        storage_key_type             = "StorageAccessKey"
        administrator_login          = azurerm_mssql_server.sql_server.administrator_login
        administrator_login_password = azurerm_mssql_server.sql_server.administrator_login_password
        authentication_type          = "Sql"
    }
}
```

With this setup, I get the following error

> Error: while import bacpac into the new database test-db (Resource Group Test-dev): Code="ImportExportJobError" Message="The ImportExport operation with Request Id '1b005b56-bccd-4484-a5e0-c2495834798a' failed due to 'The SQL instance is inaccessible because the public network interface is denied (Error 47073). Please enable public network access on the SQL Server or configure Import/Export to use Private Link per [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-import-export-private-link.'."](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-import-export-private-link.%27.%22)
>
> with module.sql_server.azurerm_mssql_database.sql_server_database, on Modules\SqlServer\main.tf line 69, in resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "sql_server_database":
> 69: resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "sql_server_database" {

This error makes sense as I have set `public_network_access_enabled = false` on my SQL Server.

For security reasons I would not like to set

```
public_network_access_enabled = true
```

so my question would be: is there a possibility to import the database without enabling network access on the server?

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-import-export-private-link?view=azuresql) I found a way to import the database using PowerShell, which should create a Privatelink for importing, but using this the Database would not be created using Terraform and would not be managed through the Terraform-State...

So does someone know of a way to import the database using Terraform with `public_network_access_enabled = false`?

(AzureRM Provider Version: 3.31)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Private Link for importing seems to be still in Preview. Preview features are rarely (or never) supported with Terraform so I would search alternatives for now.

I personally would create the database with Terraform and then manually (or with some CI/CD magic) import the required data. Generally Terraform is a bit clunky tool in managing what happens inside a database and I personally like using other tools for it.

Comment: As the database is not accessibly from a public network any suggestions on how to handle the connect? My first thoughts would be a) side-2-side vpn b) build a service in azure that handles importing on startup

Comment: So I haven't done this myself, but reading the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/2021-08-01-preview/servers/import-database?tabs=HTTP#imports-to-a-new-database,-using-private-link-for-the-sql-server-and-storage-account I would assume that making that API call does not require any networking setup as it goes through the management API

Comment: Another, generic solution would be to use self hosted ci/cd agents (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install), connect to the database directly and then execute an import. However this requires much more setup than the Management API approach. On the other hand, it then works for any operations you want to execute.